# Set to global icons

Tags: android, icons, set

so I have been searching for a good while, but can't seem to find anything about this!
I want to use the default icons that android provide so I don't have to make my own for everything. But every tutorial I can find says:

```
android:icon = "@android:drawable/star_big_on"
```

However, I'm looking for how I can do this for a marker that I have to set when created.
So I need something like this but for the default icons that android provide:

```
myMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.star_big_on));
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Androids built in icons as you may find they change in future versions and make your app inconsistent. Instead, copy the ones you need into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using:

```
myMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on));
```

To use the `android` resources.